# preg_replace pass count of matches to second parameter

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

When using `preg_replace` in PHP, is it possible to get the number of matches and pass that to the second parameter of `preg_replace`.

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$str = <<<EOF
*Samsung
This is the description text for Samsung
**Early years
Korean town
***Founders
EOF;

echo preg_replace('/(?m)^\*{1,3}([^*].*)$/', '<h {} >$1</h {}>', $str);
//Note the {} in the above. That's where the count from the regex needs to go. So we'll be create H tags based on the replacements.
```

So the final output will be:

```
<h1>Samsung</h1> // There was one `*` here
This is the description text for Samsung
<h2>Early years</h2> // There were two `*`s here
Korean town
<h3>Founders</h3> // There were three `*`s here
```

Is something like this possible? Can the count from the regex be extracted?

Comment: no, impossible, use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: As @georg said, use `preg_replace_callback`. Put `\*{1,3}` in a capture group, and then the callback can use `strlen()` to get its length, and put that where your `{}` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested use a callback to do this. You can tweak this to your needs...

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(?m)^(\*{1,3})([^*].*)$~', 
     function($m) {
         $count = strlen($m[1]);
         return "<h$count>$m[2]</h$count>";
     }, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
$str = <<<EOF
*Samsung
This is the description text for Samsung
**Early years
Korean town
***Founders
EOF;
function turnStarToHeader($m) {
    static $id = 0;
    $id++;
    return "<h$id>$m[1]</h$id>";
 }

echo preg_replace_callback('/(?m)^\*{1,3}([^*].*)$/', 'turnStarToHeader', $str);
```